# Fourier series approximation in python

Tags: python, physics

I am attempting to sum the Fourier series for every value of x, append it to an array and then set it = 0 to go again for each value. Something is wrong with the summation, I don't believe I should be getting values as small as the code returns.

```
  import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
n=int(input("Please enter value of n\n"))
x=np.linspace(0, math.pi*2, int(n/2))
f=math.sin(x[1])
print(f)
ydata=[]
xdata=[]
def func(i):
    for i in range(3, n, 2):
        f =++ (math.sin(i*math.pi)/i)
    ydata.append(f*(4/math.pi))
    f=0
for i in x:
    func(i)
print(ydata)
#f_norm=f*(4/math.pi)
plt.plot(x, ydata)
print(x)
```

Comment: `f =++` This jumps out at me as strange looking. Did you mean to write `f += ` ?

Comment: Also, you have `i` as argument but reuse the symbol `i` for a loop iterator in `func`. I don't think that's what you wanted.

Comment: As pointed by @Gilles-PhilippePaillé, your function depends on `i`, shouldn't it take `n` as and argument instead as `i` is shadowed from another scope?